# use javascript variable in HTML4 DOM application/x-mplayer2 video

Tags: javascript, html, video, get, html4

i'm new here and please excuse my english.

I'm normaly a Java developer but now i have to fix a problem with Javascript and HTML.

I start a HTML Page and give the Filepath as Get Paramter. 

First i read the Parameter with Javascript. Thats works. But i will use the Path to start a Video with  application/x-mplayer2 and i have no Idea how i can use the Path in HTML.

My Problem is to get the FILEPATH into the HTML src="". 

Can you tell me if it is possible ? Or i have to Change anything?

I can't use PHP or HTML5. It's have to work on Internet Explorer.

The video will be in mp4 Format.

This is my Code:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
HTTP_GET_VARS=new Array();
strGET=document.location.search.substr(1,document.location.search.length);
if(strGET!='')
{
gArr=strGET.split('&');
for(i=0;i<gArr.length;++i)
    {
    v='';vArr=gArr[i].split('=');
    if(vArr.length>1){v=vArr[1];}
    HTTP_GET_VARS[unescape(vArr[0])]=unescape(v);
    }
}

function GET(v)
{
if(!HTTP_GET_VARS[v]){return 'undefined';}
return HTTP_GET_VARS[v];
}




 var FILEPATH = GET('xxx');

 document.writeln (' \r\n' + FILEPATH );

 </SCRIPT>




 <object>
     <embed id="para1" type="application/x-mplayer2"
    pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/default.aspx"
    width="558" height="330"src="FILEPATH "
    showcontrols="true" showstatusbar="False" 
    showdisplay="False" autorewind="false"
    AutoStart="false">

   </embed>     
</object>
```

Thank you for your Help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of a property... you can use

```
document.getElementById('para1').setAttribute('src', 'new src value');
```

Just to clarify...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var HTTP_GET_VARS = new Array();

        strGET = document.location.search.substr(1,document.location.search.length);

        if(strGET!='')
        {
            gArr = strGET.split('&');
            for(i=0; i<gArr.length; ++i)
            {
                var v = ''; 
                var vArr = gArr[i].split('=');

                if(vArr.length>1)
                    v = vArr[1];

                HTTP_GET_VARS[unescape(vArr[0])] = unescape(v);
            }
        }

        function GET(v)
        {
            if(!HTTP_GET_VARS[v]) return 'undefined';

            return HTTP_GET_VARS[v];
        }

        var filepath = GET('xxx');
        document.getElementById('para1').setAttribute('src', filepath);

        document.writeln (' \r\n' + filepath );

    });

</script>

 <object>
     <embed id="para1" type="application/x-mplayer2"
    pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/default.aspx"
    width="558" height="330"src="FILEPATH"
    showcontrols="true" showstatusbar="False" 
    showdisplay="False" autorewind="false"
    AutoStart="false">

   </embed>     
</object>
```